# Move vertices to center of mirror modifier to join with other side

Tags: modeling, modifiers, workflow

I have this model and I would like to join the 3 vertices selected by moving them to the center of the mirror modifier.

[image]

How can I join up vertices with the other side of the mirror modifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out there is an option in the mirror modifier settings called `clipping` that lets me drag the verts right to the center and they will stop when they meet

[image]